# Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations

Tags: asp.net, linq

So here is what i am trying to do. I have tables from the DB and 1 list of member. I get the member from the asp.net membership controls and it a combined membership and profile object. I have a function that will return a list the following Mems object:

```
Public Property FirstName As String = ""
Public Property LastName As String = ""
Public Property Address1 As String = ""
Public Property Address2 As String = ""
Public Property City As String = ""
Public Property State As System.Int32 = "0"
Public Property Zip As String = ""
Public Property Title As String = ""
Public Property Phone As System.Decimal = "0"
Public Property Id As System.Int32 = "0"
Public Property UserType As System.Int32 = "0"
Public Property SSN As System.Int32 = "0"
Public Property Email As String = ""
Public Property UserName As String = ""
Public Property IsLockedOut As Boolean = False
Private Loaded As Boolean = False
```

then I have the 2 tables of Jobs and Accounts:

Jobs

```
JobId   numeric(18,0)
AccountId   numeric(18,0)
Name    varchar(50)
Frequency   int
Modifier    varchar(90)
Active  bit
sDate   date
eDate   date
```

Accounts

```
AccountId   numeric(18,0)
CompanyId   numeric(18,0)
ContactId   varchar(256)
Type    int
Name    varchar(256)
Address1    varchar(50)
Address2    varchar(50)
City    varchar(50)
State   int
Zip varchar(5)
AuthCode    varchar(10)
Comments    text
```

The output I am trying to achieve is a list of Jobs for the accounts for a particular companyid with the info from the mems. I have it working elsewhere for the accounts, but when i throw the jobs in the mix, It give me the error of:

```
Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.
```

Here is where I have gotten with the function as of the moment:

```
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
Public Shared Function JobSearch(jSon As String) As String
    Dim DamnSer As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim Search As SearchString = DamnSer.Deserialize(Of SearchString)(jSon)
    Dim myDB As New MyDbDataContext
    Dim pro As New Mems(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)



    Dim acc = From a In myDB.Accounts Where a.CompanyId = pro.Id Select a

    Dim accList = acc.Where(Function(r) r.AccountId).[Select](Function(r) r.AccountId.ToString()).ToArray()

    Dim q = From u In Util.GetMems Join a In acc On a.ContactId Equals u.UserName
            Where u.FirstName.ToLower.Contains(Search.FirstName.ToLower) And
            u.LastName.ToLower.Contains(Search.LastName.ToLower) And
            a.Name.ToLower.Contains(Search.Name.ToLower) And
            a.ContactId.ToLower.Contains(Search.Email.ToLower) And
            u.Phone.ToString.Contains(Search.Phone.ToLower) And
            a.AccountId.ToString.Contains(Search.AccountId.ToLower)
            Select New With {.FirstName = u.FirstName,
                                      .LastName = u.LastName,
                                      .Name = a.Name,
                                      .Email = u.Email,
                                      .Phone = u.Phone,
                                      .AccountId = a.AccountId,
                                      .City = a.City,
                                      .State = (From s In myDB.States Where s.StateId = a.State Select s.StateAbbr).Single
                            }
    'This is the only line i added between what I have working and this new section and it is where the error happens
    Dim qq = From j In myDB.Jobs Where accList.Contains(j.AccountId) Select New With {j.JobId, j.Name, (From z In q Where z.AccountId = j.AccountId).Single}

    Return DamnSer.Serialize(qq)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go a different route with it

```
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
Public Shared Function JobSearch(jSon As String) As String
    Dim DamnSer As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim Search As SearchString = DamnSer.Deserialize(Of SearchString)(jSon)
    Dim myDB As New MyDbDataContext
    Dim pro As New Mems(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)

    Dim acc = From a In myDB.Accounts Where a.CompanyId = pro.Id Select a

    Dim q = From u In Util.GetMems Join a In acc On a.ContactId Equals u.UserName
            Where u.FirstName.ToLower.Contains(Search.FirstName.ToLower) And
            u.LastName.ToLower.Contains(Search.LastName.ToLower) And
            a.Name.ToLower.Contains(Search.Name.ToLower) And
            a.ContactId.ToLower.Contains(Search.Email.ToLower) And
            u.Phone.ToString.Contains(Search.Phone.ToLower) And
            a.AccountId.ToString.Contains(Search.AccountId.ToLower)
            Select New With {.FirstName = u.FirstName,
                                      .LastName = u.LastName,
                                      .Name = a.Name,
                                      .Email = u.Email,
                                      .Phone = u.Phone,
                                      .AccountId = a.AccountId,
                                      .City = a.City,
                                      .State = (From s In myDB.States Where s.StateId = a.State Select s.StateAbbr).Single,
                                      .zip = a.Zip,
                                      .Locations = (From l In myDB.Locations Where l.AccountId = a.AccountId Select New With {l.AccountId, l.Address1, l.Address2, l.City, l.Comments, l.LocationId, .State = (From s In myDB.States Where s.StateId = l.State Select s.StateAbbr).Single, l.Zip,
                                          .JobCount = (From j In myDB.Jobs Where j.LocationId = l.LocationId Select j).Count}
                                    )
                            }

    Return DamnSer.Serialize(q)
End Function
```